# How do I get the first branch PID of an application in pstree command?

Tags: process, ps

I want to get PPID of chromium browser. When I launch `chromium-browser` it launches many child processes with the same name.

For example:

```
$ pidof  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
8963 8888 8710 7255 7074 6546 6540 6536 6532 6528 6524 6520 6516 6512 6506 6379 6357 6282 6258 6167 4977 2452
```

If I try to obtain PPID from child processes like:

```
$ echo $(ps -o ppid= -p $(pidof -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser)) 
6282
```

It prints PPID of chromium browser but it's not the topmost PID of `chromium-browser` according to `pstree`:

```
    ├─chromium-browse(6167)─┬─chromium-browse(6258)───chromium-browse(6282)─┬─chromium-browse(2452)─┬─{chromium-browse}(2460)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2461)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2467)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2527)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2574)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2918)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(3711)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(3984)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(4977)─┬─{chromium-browse}(4996)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5015)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5016)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5087)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5170)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5358)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(831)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(832)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6506)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6509)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6607)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6616)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6636)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6754)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6849)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7045)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(5651)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(5652)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6512)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6515)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6595)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6613)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6637)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6753)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6516)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6519)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6602)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6612)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6632)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6761)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(2492)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6378)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6520)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6522)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6600)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6623)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6629)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6752)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6524)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6527)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6596)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6617)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6638)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6766)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6528)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6531)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6605)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6622)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6639)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6758)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6353)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6532)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6534)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6598)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6618)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6642)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6756)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6788)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6536)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6539)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6599)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6615)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6630)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6751)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6449)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6450)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6540)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6545)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6601)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6619)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6641)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6760)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(6546)─┬─{chromium-browse}(6549)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6606)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6614)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6631)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6759)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(7074)─┬─{chromium-browse}(7079)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7081)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7082)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7099)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7100)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7103)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(7109)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(7255)─┬─{chromium-browse}(7257)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7259)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7260)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7264)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7265)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7268)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(7270)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(8710)─┬─{chromium-browse}(8713)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8714)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8715)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8718)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8719)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8850)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(17470)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(19250)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(23721)
    │                       │                                               ├─chromium-browse(8888)─┬─{chromium-browse}(8891)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8894)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8895)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8899)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8902)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8911)
    │                       │                                               │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(9469)
    │                       │                                               │                       └─{chromium-browse}(9471)
    │                       │                                               └─chromium-browse(8963)─┬─{chromium-browse}(8968)
    │                       │                                                                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8969)
    │                       │                                                                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8970)
    │                       │                                                                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8971)
    │                       │                                                                       ├─{chromium-browse}(8977)
    │                       │                                                                       └─{chromium-browse}(8989)
    │                       ├─chromium-browse(6357)─┬─chromium-browse(6379)
    │                       │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6380)
    │                       │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6381)
    │                       │                       └─{chromium-browse}(6382)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6255)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6283)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6284)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6285)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6288)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6289)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6290)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6291)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6292)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6293)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6310)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6311)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6312)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6313)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6314)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6315)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6316)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6317)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6318)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6319)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6320)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6323)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6351)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6355)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6356)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6375)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6385)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6386)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6455)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6505)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6708)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6781)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(6783)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7075)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(7076)
    │                       ├─{chromium-browse}(9053)
    │                       └─{chromium-browse}(9089)
```

How can get the first branch PID of chromium-browser (`├─chromium-browse(6167)─`)?

Comment: If you're looking for the top level chromium process, it should be the one with parent process id of 1 (init), try using `pgrep -P1 chromium` to find its PID

Comment: @bsd wow you spotted it, it works. Would you post it as an answer?

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the top level chromium process, it could be the one with parent process id of 1 (init), try using `pgrep -P1 chromium` to find its PID.

You may wish to try using `ps ef` to see processes listed in a tree like structure to find a parent. Note: `ps` switches are `ef` and not `-ef`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It should also be possible with regex tools such as sed, awk or grep.

Comment: This will break if your process is started, for example, in a shell. The shell would be the parent process of the browser.

Comment: I don't want to annoy you, but `$$` gives the process id of the *current* shell. That does not imply that this is the parent process of the browser; it can be started in another shell. However +1, good answer anyway. =)

Comment: `$BASHPID` is no better than `$$` (it's the same except in subshells, and except that it works only in bash).

Answer (score 2):

You could try with `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -o chromium
```

The `-o` flag will only print the oldest (least recently started) of the matching processes. If all your chromium instances are child processes of that parent process with pid `6167`, then this must be the oldest `chromium-browser` process, therefore `pgrep -o` should print that pid.

---

Tested with an apache instance:

```
$ pstree -p
init(1)-+-acpid(1296)
        |-apache2(1312)-+-apache2(29259)
        |               |-apache2(29260)-+-{apache2}(29262)
        |               |                |-{apache2}(29263)
[...]
        |               `-apache2(29354)-+-{apache2}(29356)
        |                                |-{apache2}(29357)
[...]
```

---

```
$ pgrep -o apache2
1312
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried it like `pgrep -oaf /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser` but it gives me different PPID `6506` . chromium-browser process PIDs are still actual, they are as it is in posted in question. By the way `pgrep -o chromium-browser` returns empty string in my distro. I have to use `-oaf` flags.

Comment: What is your distro?

Comment: it's Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault, `pgrep -o chromium-browser` returns empty string but `pgrep -o chromium` works and gives me the exact first branch PPID

Comment: Ok good, I tought from the example in your question that the process can be matched by the full name.

Answer (score 1):

`pgrep` is the way to go; I wrote this mostly as a `bash` exercise, but in case it's useful to anyone else:

It sets up a function that accepts one parameter -- a process name that presumably matches something in the `ps -eo comm` output. It reads the `ps` output, setting up an array of pids and parent pids for processes that match. Once that's done, it loops through the matched pids to find the one that has a parent pid that was **not** in the original list/array.

```
# searches the 'ps' listing for matching ($1) processes,
# then displays the "ancestor" PID -- the process that has a parent PID
# that has a different process name
function ancestor () {
  # must pass a parameter (process name)
  [ -z "$1" ] && return
  local -a array
  local ppid pid comm
  # can't pipe `ps ... | while` as that creates a subshell that loses $array
  while read ppid pid comm
  do
    [ "$comm" = "$1" ] && array[$pid]=$ppid
  done < <(ps -eo ppid,pid,comm)
  # loop through each pid in array and see which value (ppid) is not a member of the array
  for pid in ${!array[@]}
  do
    [ ${array[${array[$pid]}]-unset} = "unset" ] && { echo $pid; break; }
  done
}
```